# Script not flowing to first div only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a script used to grab and spit out some of our data. The way it works is we create a variable then send it to the div id's located below.

```
function loadPregame() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $.getJSON("_schedule_" + seasontype + ".json", 
    function(data){
        var game = data.gscd.g;
        var status = game[gamenum].st;
        //home team top nav
        var homeTeamTop='<div class="homelogo col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left">';
        homeTeamTop+='<img src="logos/' + game[gamenum].h["ta"] + '.png" class="img-responsive" />';
        homeTeamTop+='</div>';
        homeTeamTop+='<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 scorepad">';
        homeTeamTop+='<span class="record score">' + game[gamenum].h["re"] + '</span>';
        //homeTeam+='<br /><span id="homerank" class="rank"></span>';
        homeTeamTop+='</div>';
        // HOME TEAM
        var homeTeam='<div class="homelogo col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left">';
        homeTeam+='<img src="logos/' + game[gamenum].h["ta"] + '.png" class="img-responsive" />';
        homeTeam+='</div>';
        homeTeam+='<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 scorepad">';

            homeTeam+='<span class="record score">' + game[gamenum].h["re"] + '</span>';
            //homeTeam+='<br /><span id="homerank" class="rank"></span>';

        homeTeam+='</div>';


        // VISITOR TEAM
        var visTeam='<div class="awaylogo col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-right">';
        visTeam+='<img src="logos/' + game[gamenum].v["ta"] + '.png" class="img-responsive" />';
        visTeam+='</div>';
        visTeam+='<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 scorepad pull-left">';

        visTeam+='<span class="record score">' + game[gamenum].v["re"] + '</span>';
            //visTeam+='<br /><span id="visrank" class="rank"></span>';

        visTeam+='</div>';





        document.getElementById("homeTeamTop").innerHTML=homeTeamTop;
        //document.getElementById("visTeamTwo").innerHTML=visTeamTwo;
        document.getElementById("visTeam").innerHTML=visTeam;
        document.getElementById("homeTeam").innerHTML=homeTeam;

    });
} //end function
```

What I can't seem to figure out is why the homeTeamTop won't proceed to my "HomeTeamTop" div. The others, which come after in progress have no issue. I've tried changing up the variable names and even redoing each manually. I then tried using the same info in the variables that work, but to no avail. `<div id="visTeam"></div>` and `<div id="homeTeam"></div>` which come next in progression print just fine. Is there a var_dump function as in PHP that I can use to see what's being rendered for homeTeamTop?

```
<div id="homeTeamTop"></div>
<div id="visTeam"></div>
<div id="homeTeam"></div>
```

Comment: *"Below is a piece of json"* - what..? JSON..? Where..?

Comment: Updated. Hopefully correct now. @TJ  . Thanks for pointing out the copy error.

Comment: We do not see the data that is rendered from variable `game` Maybe this is not encoded right and it does not make your html valid.

Comment: @BeaudinnGreve It's exactly the same as the others. The same set of data in fact. I'm trying to render it twice on the page. So homeTeam and homeTeamTop are exactly the same. homeTeam renders, but homeTeamTop doesn't. That was my initial thought as well. Maybe corrupt data, but it only skips the homeTeamTop variation.

Comment: What do you see if you inspect the "homeTeamTop" div? It's contents are completely empty?

Comment: Yes, it's empty and grayed out as well. Just an empty div. @EdgarSanchez

Comment: What happens if you do the following in js console document.getElementById("homeTeamTop")?

Comment: @Msencenb I get the following `document.getElementById("homeTeamTop")

<div id="homeTeamTop">`

Comment: @Msencenb did you get that last post?